# Broken pipe on my python script when piping to "head"

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script that I've released on PyPI that has strange behavior when you pipe it to "head" (in Ubuntu on WSL is where I'm using it, though I assume it applies more generally). I would guess that only the code that's outputting to stdout is relevant, so I'm putting that here.

```
for perm in coeff_perms:
    val = coeff_dict[perm]
    if val != 0:                    
        if display_positive:
            if expand(val) != 0:
                val = compute_positive_rep(val)
            else:
                val = 0
        if val!=0:
            if ascode:
                print(f"{str(trimcode(perm)):>{width}}  {str(val).replace('**','^').replace('*',' ')}")    
            else:
                print(f"{str(perm):>{width}}  {str(val).replace('**','^').replace('*',' ')}")
```

When I run this and pipe it to `head`, it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matthematics/.local/bin/schubmult_double", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/home/matthematics/.local/lib/python3.11/site- 
   packages/schubmult/schubmult_double/schubmult_double.py", line 161, in main
    print(f"{str(trimcode(perm)):>{width}}  {str(val).replace('**','^').replace('*',' ')}")
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Why is it doing this? Is it because of the `:>{width}`? Importantly, how can I fix it? It shouldn't be a problem to pipe the output anywhere.

Comment: @Brian61354270 So I'm reading this and it seems like nonsense that I should have to handle a Linux-only exception in a platform independent command line script. In any case wrapping it with `try...except BrokenPipeError` works.